# How to format the date into ISO 8601 ? Is there any predefined method available in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, next.js

Right now i am using this function

```
const setDuration = () => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const newDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
        
        const year = newDate.getUTCFullYear();
        const month = String(newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');  
        const day = String(newDate.getUTCDate()).padStart(2, '0');
      
        const hours = String(newDate.getUTCHours()).padStart(2, '0');
        const minutes = String(newDate.getUTCMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
        const seconds = String(newDate.getUTCSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
        const milliseconds = String(newDate.getUTCMilliseconds()).padEnd(7, '0');

        const timeZoneOffset = newDate.getTimezoneOffset();
        const timeZoneOffsetHours = Math.abs(Math.floor(timeZoneOffset / 60));
        const timeZoneOffsetMinutes = Math.abs(timeZoneOffset % 60);
        const timeZoneOffsetSign = timeZoneOffset < 0 ? '-' : '+';
        return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}.${milliseconds}${timeZoneOffsetSign}${String(timeZoneOffsetHours).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(timeZoneOffsetMinutes).padStart(2, '0')}`;
    }
```

I am Expecting this format => 2023-09-14T10:12:03.7380000+00:00

Comment: [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)? JS Dates are only accurate to the ms and all UTC by default.

Comment: No, I don't want in toISOString()

Comment: You are currently rendering all UTC time parts, but then appending an arbitrary timezone offset.

Comment: Yes, and because of this function, I am getting the output as a String not in date Object, So I am seeing a better approach to do the same.

Comment: duplicate [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I have checked this already, I would request you to plz go through the question once again.

I want it in this format => 2023-09-14T10:12:03.7380000+00:00

milliseconds can be less than 7 or maybe 3

Comment: milliseconds are always 3 decimal places, and anything beyond that is not representable by a js Date. Your question seems to show a large degree of confusion about how Date objects in js as well as the usage of timezones

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in JavaScript you can format a date into ISO 8601 format using the toISOString method available on Date objects.

For your specific use you could use it like this:

```js
const setDuration = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const timeZoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    const timeZoneOffsetHours = String(Math.floor(Math.abs(timeZoneOffset) / 60)).padStart(2, '0');
    const timeZoneOffsetMinutes = String(Math.abs(timeZoneOffset) % 60).padStart(2, '0');
    const timeZoneOffsetSign = timeZoneOffset < 0 ? '+' : '-';
    
    const isoString = date.toISOString();
    return `${isoString.slice(0, -1)}${timeZoneOffsetSign}${timeZoneOffsetHours}:${timeZoneOffsetMinutes}`;
};
```

Comment: From this way, I am getting the date as a String not in the Date object.

Comment: A date object does not have format. The format is applied when converting to a string.

You can convert back to date object by doing: const dateObject = new Date(setDuration());

Comment: But in this way, it is changing the format

Comment: applying a timezone offset to a UTC time doesn't make any sense, and fundamentally changes the moment being represented.

Answer (score -1):

Is it 2023, every language has refactored its date API (see java evolution from Date, to Calendar, to Instant/DateTime), or wants to.
Also it seems you want nanosecond (micro?), bu JS do not offer such possibility without the use of libraries. (you did not specify if browser or node runtime)

It is js, so there are plentiful of large use libraries. So the case of not using libraries because you do not want to is wrong.

Why not use a library (luxon, momen) that is tested to work in plenty of scenarios ? (like yours)